# How to make a text of several letters animate, only with an animation

Tags: 2d, unity, animation

I wonder if it is possible to create an animation in a text with a single "animation". The problem is that for me to reach the desired effect I need to create an animation for each letter, as each one will appear a screen location. There is possibility to create this effect with just an animation? Remember that the deed is not the same as an animation into a sprite (one over another).

I did the animation for entering each letter on the screen, Curve > Transform > Position. (in the picture I tried to simulate using arrows to input source for each letter).

[image]

Comment: Make every  lette a child of a game object. Then create the animation in the parent game object. Animate the position for every letter in its own curve/channel.